# Django reverse lookup

Tags: django

I have a URL structure which includes a year/month/day/slug format

Example: 2014/Jan/25/Another_blog/

In my models i have a get_absolute_url function

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    # Format date to yyyy/mon/dd format
    datestr = format_date(self.publication_date,'%Y/%b/%d')
    slugstr = datestr + '/' + self.machine_name
    return (str(slugstr))
```

The URL's entry is

```
url(r'^(?P\d{4})/(?P[-\w]+)/(?P\d{1,2})/(?P[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$',
        PostDetails.as_view(), name='postdetails'),
```

In my view i am returning the record with a helper

```
# Helper
def get_post(self, slug):
    return Post.objects.get(machine_name=slug)
```

When using this in the template using {{ post.get_absolute_url }} it works well

What i am trying to do is get a working test using reverse()

```
def test_post_detail_view(self):
    a = self.create_post()
    url = reverse('postdetails')
    resp = self.client.get(url)
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

I have tried:

url = reverse('postdetails', args=[a.machine_name])

url = reverse('postdetails', kwargs={'slug': a.machine_name})

But know i'm not getting the reverse logic right.

The test output is:

"arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'postdetails' with arguments

Any advice or pointers would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give all four args, e.g.

```
reverse("postdetails", args=('2014', 'Jan', '25', a.machine_name))
```